Windows Forms databinding to radio buttons
I am trying to bind two boolean properties to two radio buttons. When the form loads, the two radio buttons are all unchecked. When I clicked the first radio button, it became checked. However, when I tried to click the second radio button, the first one stayed checked and the second one was still unchecked. If I clicked the second radio button again, both radio buttons are unchecked. If I clicked the second radio button again, it would become checked. Basically, it took 3 clicks to make the second radio button checked. Same applies to first radio button if I first checked the second radio button.
I have a viewmodel class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isCashPayment;
        private bool _isChequePayment;

        public bool IsCashPayment
        {
            get => _isCashPayment;
            set
            {
                if (_isCashPayment == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _isCashPayment = value;


                // Notify the UI that the property has changed.
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool IsChequePayment
        {
            get => _isChequePayment;
            set
            {
                if (_isChequePayment == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _isChequePayment = value;

                // Notify the UI that the property has changed.
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        // Notify the UI that one of the properties has changed.
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}

The form code:

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form7 : Form
    {
        private ViewModel _viewModel;

        public Form7()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewModel = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rdbCash.DataBindings.Add(nameof(rdbCash.Checked), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.IsCashPayment), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            rdbCheque.DataBindings.Add(nameof(rdbCheque.Checked), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.IsChequePayment), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }
    }
}

Form designer generated code:
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form7
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            rdbCash = new RadioButton();
            rdbCheque = new RadioButton();
            button1 = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // rdbCash
            // 
            rdbCash.AutoSize = true;
            rdbCash.Location = new Point(20, 66);
            rdbCash.Name = "rdbCash";
            rdbCash.Size = new Size(51, 19);
            rdbCash.TabIndex = 0;
            rdbCash.Text = "Cash";
            rdbCash.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // rdbCheque
            // 
            rdbCheque.AutoSize = true;
            rdbCheque.Location = new Point(136, 66);
            rdbCheque.Name = "rdbCheque";
            rdbCheque.Size = new Size(66, 19);
            rdbCheque.TabIndex = 1;
            rdbCheque.Text = "Cheque";
            rdbCheque.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            button1.Location = new Point(15, 28);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            button1.TabIndex = 2;
            button1.Text = "button1";
            button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form7
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(800, 450);
            Controls.Add(button1);
            Controls.Add(rdbCheque);
            Controls.Add(rdbCash);
            Name = "Form7";
            Text = "Form7";
            Load += Form7_Load;
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();
        }

        #endregion

        private RadioButton rdbCash;
        private RadioButton rdbCheque;
        private Button button1;
    }
}

I am trying to use databinding instead of the traditional radio button checked event hander. I am expecting the radio button would change its state when clicked and also change the value of the binding property. I tried to put the two radio buttons in a group box and the result was the same.
What I have observed is when when the first radio button was selected and I clicked the second radio button, the property setter bound to first radio button was called first and passed the value of false, then the property setter bound to second radio button was called. However, instead of passing true value, the setter get the false value, therefore, the radio button is unchecked when clicked.

Checked state needs to change more than once, with the same value, so remove this: if (_isCashPayment == value) { return; } and set DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation

Hi, Jimi, the solution you provided does not work. Even though the UI looks good, the radio buttons are properly checked/unchecked after each click, but the properties bound to the radio button are not in sync with the radio buttons' checked state. After several clicks on both the radio buttons, the "_isCashPayment" and "_isChequePayment" are both true.

I probably handle data bindings and validations differently. To keep it simple, use a BindingSource as the source of the bindings (e.g., var rbSource = new BindingSource(_viewModel, null);), use it as the data source of the bindings of your RadioButtons (instead of setting _viewModel directly), keeping DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged in this case. Then remove the OnPropertyChanged() call, otherwise you set the same property twice, causing a duplicated, cascading, effect

As you probably know, RadioButtons that have the same Parent, collaborate (in a way) to handle the Value currently selected, since just one of the RadioButtons can have a true Value. The others must change their Value to false. So, there's already a PropertyChanged-like event under the hood. No reason to do that twice on user code, hence duplicating notifications that are already been sent to the host

I tried to define the two properties just as { get; set; }, not property change notification anymore, the radio button binding code stays the same. However, the radio buttons still do not behavior correctly. I need to clicked twice to select a radio button. I think the winforms databinding framework has issues.

Did you use a BindingSource, as specified, or not? That's the key point. The main objects for data bindings in WinForms are the BindingSource and the BindingList. The former, when instantiated, and the context requires it, creates an instance of the latter (to handle collections of objects internally). These two (main) objects generate Property / data member notification changes in WinForms

Thanks, Jimi. You are right, the BindingSource helps. However, if I remove the OnPropertyChanged() call, it would not be a two way databinding. If I change the binding property value in the code, the radio button state in the UI would not change.

No. It wouldn't, because of the nature of the internal functionality of this Control mentioned already. For that, you either set the Control's Checked Property directly or, for example, add a method to the ViewModel that sets the property and notifies the change. E.g., public void SetIsCashPayment(bool value) { IsCashPayment = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCashPayment)); }. You can also use a State flag that is set when the change is caused by internal / user code, so OnPropertyChanged() is called only when this State is set

Another option is (probably, I haven't tested it) to call OnPropertyChanged() only when value = true. Still using a BindingSource as mediator

Jimi, I think you are right. Calling OnProperyChanged() only when the value is true should work. When user clicks a radio button, two status change events will be triggered: One for the previous checked radio button to uncheck and then for the clicked radio button to check. The OnProprtyChange() can only be called once in the second event. If it is called in first event, the radio button states would mess up.

With the help of Jimi and the this posting: MVVM radiobuttons, I finally got the radio button two-way data binding working in windows forms.
In the form.cs file, we create a BindingSource and use it to bind the radio buttons.
    private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource rdBindingSource = new BindingSource(_viewModel, null);
        rdbCash.DataBindings.Add(nameof(rdbCash.Checked), rdBindingSource, nameof(_viewModel.IsCashPayment), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        rdbCheque.DataBindings.Add(nameof(rdbCheque.Checked), rdBindingSource, nameof(_viewModel.IsChequePayment), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

In the ViewModel, we define an enum object to hold the radio button value. The setters of the radio button binding properties would not directly trigger the PropertyChanged() event. Instead, they change the payment source property and payment source property trigger the PropertyChanged() event only when it is changed. The key point here is when radio button is clicked, there are two events would happen: first the previous selected radio button would change the state to false (unchecked), second the current selected radio button would change the state to true (checked). The PropertyChanged() event should be fired only in the second event. If it is fired in first event, it would mess up the radio button state. The second event would actually pass the radio button state as false (unchecked).
internal enum PaymentSource
{
    None,
    Cash,
    Cheque
}

internal partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PaymentSource _paymentSource;

    public bool IsCashPayment
    {
        get { return Source == PaymentSource.Cash; }
        set
        {
            if (value && Source != PaymentSource.Cash)
            {
                Source = PaymentSource.Cash;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsChequePayment
    {
        get { return Source == PaymentSource.Cheque; }
        set
        {
            if (value && Source != PaymentSource.Cheque)
            {
                Source = PaymentSource.Cheque;
            }
        }
    }

    public PaymentSource Source
    {
        get { return this._paymentSource; }
        set
        {
            if (this._paymentSource == value)
                return;

            this._paymentSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsCashPayment));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChequePayment));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    // Notify the UI that one of the properties has changed.
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

